# Poner imagen estática que active iframe

Tags: html, iframe, lazy-loading

Tengo un iframe activo en una web que está gastando muchos recursos e impide el renderizado correcto de la página. Ya que el lazyload no me está funcionando, quisiera que, en lugar de visualizar el iframe, apareciera una imagen estática y que clicando encima de ella (o de un botón) se cargara efectivamente el contenido del iframe, que ahora mismo es éste:

```html
<iframe title="Report Section" width="1600" height="680" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMTU5MDI4MmEtNzY0Yi00ZDFhLWFjMTYtOGUzOGIxZjI0MGFkIiwidCI6IjUxZjI3ZTY3LTBkODgtNDkyMC04YTBiLWU1OTg2NmRhMTBmNyIsImMiOjl9" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true">< /iframe>
```

¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: ¿Similar a [esto](/a/255929)? Recuerda además que preguntar en [es.so] debe ser tu _último recurso_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.